# re.findall() does not return all characters

Tags: python, regex

I have pattern like this (finding 3 word abbreviations)

```
s='([A-Z][a-z]+ ){2,4}\([A-Z]{2,4}\)'
```

and I want to find

```
line='National Health Service (NHS)'
p=re.findall(s,line)
```

but p is only ['Service '] and not the whole string. Why?

Comment: Why do you want the whole string? It's the same as not doing anything it all.

Answer (score 4):

You are not grouping the match correctly, use this instead:

```
s='(?:[A-Z][a-z]+ ){2,4}\([A-Z]{2,4}\)'
```

`.findall()` returns the whole match, unless you define capturing groups (`(...)`), at which point it'll return the results contained in the group instead. The above pattern uses a *non-capturing* group instead (`(?:...)`). Since that leaves your expression without any capturing groups, `.findall()` returns full matches again.

Comment: This is correct, but it would be helpful to explain why.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: yeah, sorry, was out of time there for a bit.